# How to get data from BigQuery ordered by appeared order?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am confused to get data from BQ ordered by appeared order.
Given the following table (named as `FRUIT`), what sql is the best to get data ordered by appeared order? In this example, I want to get (Orange, Apple, Banana)

| name | price |
| --- | --- |
| Orange | 100 |
| Apple | 200 |
| Banana | 150 |

The following sql is executable, but I understand that it is not guaranteed to get data by appeared order, because `ORDER BY` is not specified in `OVER` clause. (Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#row_number)

```
SELECT
    F.name
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as row_number FROM FRUIT
) as F
ORDER BY
    F.row_number
```

Please tell me the best way to do what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want something like that:

```
row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY f.appeared ORDER BY f.appeared desc) as rank
```

or

```
row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY f.name,f.price ORDER BY f.name,f.price desc) as rank
```